# Border appears to be thicker in different lines

Tags: html, css, border

I have given a simple css rule:

> border-bottom: 1px solid #999794

for the menu links, but it seems that the border which apppears is thicker is some lines than others. How can i be sure that the line of the border has the same thickness everywhere?

Comment: Can you post the some `html` and more `css` too?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will just apply to the bottom border so if you have another rule `border :2px solid #999794` then this will likely cause the border to seem thicker. There is likely a conflicting css rule somewhere

Comment: You may be right, but I think it would be wise not to try answering this question until we have all the necessary information. In the meantime this may be better as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code is beeing processed - but if for somehow the menu is auto generated you might have some double divs somewhere - that will result in a double `border-bottom`.

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cLz1rLq8/1/

Comment: You may be right, but I think it would be wise not to try answering this question until we have all the necessary information. In the meantime this may be better as a comment. (Comment text shamelessly copied) :)

Comment: at that example where is your double css which causing the problem??

Comment: @Paulie_D commenting others questions/answers requires 50 reputation so answering is my only option.

Comment: @vsld between Item2 and Item3

Comment: I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not abuse the answer system. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!